# django - calling functions form one file to another

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I would like keep reusing some functions I've created on many of my django views so I don't have to write them over and over on every view.

So I created a folder with a `__init__.py` in it. In the same folder I also created a `myfunctions.py` file where I placed my functions I would like to reuse on my django views.

Here is just a very simple test function I put in `myfunctions.py` to see if if I can reuse the function and especially the variable from that function in my views:

```
def test_function():
    test_variable = 1
```

I would like to just call the `test_function()` on a view and to deliver the test_variable value (of 1 in this case) on a template I created. The template for theat view has already a tag `{{ test_valiable }}`.

My problem is that when I call the `test_function()` on my view I don't see the  `test_variable` value passed to the `{{ test_valiable }}` tag in the template associated with my view.

The way I called the function in my view is:

```
test_function()
```

What am I not doing right?

Comment: I'm out of fingers. I recommend going over the Python tutorial again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

test_variable is a local variable so you cant see it after function finished.
You should rewrite your function to this:

```
def test_function():
    test_variable = 1
    return test_variable
```

And use it in a views.py

```
def View(request):
   result = test_function()
   return render_to_response('template', {'test_valiable' : result })
```

Comment: On my functions I forgot to put the return that's why it didn't give me anything back :). Just learning form my mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear.

I think you must use templatetags or contextprocessors as the specific case may be.

Comment: I know it's little confusing, and I apologize for that. I'll try again. So, I created a file where I put all the functions that I need to reuse in many of my django views to void code duplication. All I need is a easy way to make those functions I wrote just show in my django views without retyping what's inside thatm. Usually I just need to pass on argument to them but nothing else.